# Determining why self-insert-command using commands for wrong mode

Tags: emacs

My emacs is somehow getting misconfigured, so that SPC in non-C modes is trying to do C-mode stuff.  If I set `debug-on-error` to true and press space in a shell buffer, I get this backtrace.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  looking-at(nil)
  c-state-semi-safe-place(465791)
  c-literal-limits(nil nil)
  c-mask-paragraph(nil t do-auto-fill)
  c-do-auto-fill()
  self-insert-command(1)
  call-interactively(self-insert-command nil nil)
  command-execute(self-insert-command)
```

I do not have a good way to reproduce it, but it happens fairly consistently when I load my (large, complicated) .emacs and work for a few hours.

It is entirely possible that I set something wrong in my .emacs, or it could be one of the packages I've recently added.  I can probably figure out the problem if I know where to look.  However, `debug-when-behavior-of-space-command-is-changed` does not seem to be a built-in option.

What are good options for figuring out what is changing the behavior of `self-insert-command`?

I am using:

```
GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21)
 of 2015-04-10 on builder10-9.porkrind.org
```

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DebugFileLoading

Comment: Check `post-self-insert-hook` for `c-do-auto-fill`.  If it's there, the quick fix would then be to remove that function from the hook.  The better fix would be to track down how it gets added. Bisecting your init.el is a good general strategy.  BTW this is in the documentation for `self-insert-command` (`C-h f self-insert-command`).

Comment: Looking more closely at the docs, `auto-fill-function` is probably more likely.